# DROP and CREATE on Amazon RDS MySQL Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it safe to connect to my MySQL RDS Amazon instance and run a `DROP` and `CREATE` on the database (Basically re-create the database)?

Example:

```
DROP DATABASE <db_name>;
CREATE DATABASE <db_name>;
```

I am just worried that there are some background "fingerprints" that will be wiped, like the database backup etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the instance being reserved and not the database (or a database), all databases on the instance will be backed-up.

Watch out, only InnoDB tables will be backed-up on the Automatic backups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that could cause any trouble with backups.

Comment: Due to the instance being reserved and not the database, all databases on the instance will be backed-up.